# Unable to count the number of matches in Vim

Tags: vim, count, match

How can you count the number of matches in Vim?

For instance, for the text

```
<?
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
:%s/<?//ng
```

See `:h count-items`.

Comment: I get the error message "Trailing characters". I tried the code with ":set report=0" too.

Comment: I would try it again, the help for Trailing Characters describes "An argument has been added to an Ex command that does not permit one."

Comment: Hrmm .. Sorry Masi, don't know what is going on for you.  I just double check this in a vim buffer on my machine, and it worked ok.

Comment: If you copy/paste the code from a web browser you may pick up a trailing newline (^M). Try typing it in manually.

Comment: @Brian: I found the source of the problem. The Vim at my server is version 6.3. The code works great when I run it on Vim 7.2. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 9):

[Count-items](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tips.html#count-items) describes what you are after.

```
:%s/<?/whatever/ng
```

This is the substitution command, but the n flag avoids the actual substitution.

Answer (score 1):

```
:help count-items
```

In VIM 6.3, here's how you'd do it:

```
:set report=0
:%s/<?/&/g   # returns the count without substitution
```

In VIM 7.2, here's how you'd do it:

```
:%s/<?/&/gn   # returns the count without substitution
```