# Show Count of Matches in Vim

Tags: search, vim

There is a nice feature in Google Chrome when you do a search. It tells you the number of matches there is for the keyword you are searching for. However, in Vim I don't see such a feature. Some people suggested using `%s/pattern//gn` or similar:

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Count_number_of_matches_of_a_pattern
[Unable to count the number of matches in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647049/unable-to-count-the-number-of-matches-in-vim)

But that is quite long really!! I am looking for the count when a press the '*', '%', or do any search using '/' and '?'.

Any idea?

Comment: You might consider asking this in [superuser.com](http://superuser.com). I won't vote to close, even if this is off-topic, just because this might be an appropriate forum to find *vim* users.

Comment: (And SU wouldn't be a good forum as the answer requires scripting, and please stop scattering the people that provide advanced answers!)

Comment: I completely agree with Luc: in the stackoverflow faq (http://stackoverflow.com/faq), it says that "if your question generally covers... software tools commonly used by programmers ...then you're in the right place to ask your question!".  Therefore, this is definitely not off-topic.

Comment: @Luc, thanks for the comments. What do you mean by "scattering the people that provide advanced answers!"?

Comment: @AI, so you consider Vim not a tool commonly used by programmers? Though I am referring to Google Chrome here, but I myself am using Vim for programming mostly.

Comment: I mean that we can never know how simple an answer will be. I've given some examples there: http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309/are-questions-about-vi-vim-and-other-clones-on-topic-here/368#368 and there: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-so-or-su

Comment: By scattering vim questions on all SE/SO/SU site, we are lowering the global quality of the answers. @Promather, As fas as I'm concerned, you've chosen the right forum.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood your comments. I thought you both agree that this is not the right place to ask this question. Well, to be honest, I don't quite like many closures that is happening here. For me (and let me know what you think), the law is used to help people not restrict them. So the idea behind having the ability to close questions is to avoid StackOverflow turning into a spam website, but that doesn't we should close any question just because it is 5% out of topic. It seems that people enjoy closing questions :-) Who knows, may be I will be the same when I have much points :D

Comment: @Promather: When I agreed with Luc, I meant that I'm convinced that  you have chosen the right forum.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I misunderstand you at the beginning :-) As you can read in my comment to @Luc, I am becoming paranoid because I frequently get my questions closed :-) Look at this question for example and read my comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/reviewing-ielts-test-in-3-days

Answer (score 69, accepted):

### Modern Vim

Starting with **Vim 8.1.1270**, there's [a new feature](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/9dfa3139198b38b28673e251a3756430065914e9) in core to show the current match position. NeoVim enables this functionality by default, but standard Vim does not.

To enable it in standard Vim, run:

```
:set shortmess-=S
```

<sup>Originally mentioned below in [Ben's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1390430/ben) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58886067/1359343), and added here for visibility.</sup>

### Older Versions

In Vim 7.4+, the [IndexedSearch](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1682) plugin can be used.

Check [henrik/vim-indexed-search](https://github.com/henrik/vim-indexed-search) on GitHub to ensure you get the latest version.

Comment: That seems to be the best answer. I will try it and see if it works well to mark your answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: Looks very interesting.  Just be careful that it doesn't cause other plugins to stop working since it's redefining some fairly fundamental keys.

Comment: There is a newer version of this plugin, with included documentation and more features, at [GitHub – henrik/vim-indexed-search](https://github.com/henrik/vim-indexed-search).

Comment: A great answer, unfortunately doesn't handle >99 matches well :(

Answer (score 24):

I don't know of a direct way of doing it, but you could make use of the way `:%s///` uses the last search as the default pattern:

```
:nmap ,c :%s///gn
```

You should then be able to do a search and then hit `,c` to report the number of matches.

The only issue will be that `*` and `#` ignore `'smartcase'`, so the results might be off by a few  after using `*`.  You can get round this by doing `*` followed by `/`<kbd>Up</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd> and then `,c`.

Comment: You can do it like this to handle the `'smartcase'` case appropriately: `nnoremap ,c :%s/<C-R>=&ignorecase ? '\c' : '\C'<CR><C-R>///gn<CR>`

Answer (score 13):

One addition to @Al's answer: if you want to make vim show it automatically in the statusline, try adding the following to the vimrc:

```
let s:prevcountcache=[[], 0]
function! ShowCount()
    let key=[@/, b:changedtick]
    if s:prevcountcache[0]==#key
        return s:prevcountcache[1]
    endif
    let s:prevcountcache[0]=key
    let s:prevcountcache[1]=0
    let pos=getpos('.')
    try
        redir => subscount
        silent %s///gne
        redir END
        let result=matchstr(subscount, '\d\+')
        let s:prevcountcache[1]=result
        return result
    finally
        call setpos('.', pos)
    endtry
endfunction
set ruler
let &statusline='%{ShowCount()} %<%f %h%m%r%=%-14.(%l,%c%V%) %P'
```

Comment: Could I request the version that incorporates ignorecase? :P

Answer (score 11):

Here's a cheap solution ... I used Find and Replace All in Vim. No fancy scripting. I did a Find X and Replace All with X. At the end, Vim reports "2134 substitutions on 9892 lines". X appeared 2134 times. Use :q! to quit the file without saving it. No harm done.

Comment: Or `replace all` replacing with the same string that you're searching for -- with the exception of some capitalization issues depending on your settings, you shouldn't change anything. Worst case, you're a `u` away from undoing it anyhow. Smart trick. ;^)

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure exactly what version added it, but this is built into Vim now, you just need to:

```
:set shortmess-=S
```

Added sometime in the 8.1.x patches (as of this writing we're at 8.1.2300).

Answer (score 3):

You already have a good wealth of answers, but it seems to me that there is still one 
more approach to this problem.

This is actually something I had to deal with a few days ago. I added a function and a mapping
in such a way that you hit the mapping when the cursor is under the word you want to count
and it returns the number of matches.

The Function:

```
" Count number of occurances of a word
function Count(word)
    let count_word = "%s/" . a:word . "//gn"
    execute count_word
endfunction
```

And the mapping:

```
" Count current word 
nmap <Leader>w <Esc>:call Count(expand("<cword>"))<CR>
```

Comment: I suggest storing your previous search register with: `:let old_query = getreg('/')` and restoring at the end with: `:call setreg('/', old_query)`.  Here my "preserve" function to vim: https://pastebin.com/GZctZxdb and here the neovim version: https://pastebin.com/2SpeWFC0

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively from what @Al suggests you can map the key combination to write most of the line and then move the cursor to the position where the actual pattern is inserted:

> :nmap ,c ^[:%s///gn^[OD^[OD^[OD^[OD

Where '^[' is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+V,<kbd>Esc</kbd> and '^[OD' is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+V,<kbd>Left</kbd>

Then pressing ',c' will go into command mode, enter the pattern and leave the cursor over the second '/', ready to insert the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

This plugin does just that.
https://github.com/osyo-manga/vim-anzu

When searching for a word in vim, it will display word count on the statusline. It also has the option to display next to the searched word ie. *this_is_my_sample_word (3/12)*, or  *this_is_my_sample_word(7/12)*. This basically says: this is the 3rd or 7th occurrence out of 12 total occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

another nice vim plugin for that:
https://github.com/google/vim-searchindex

will be shown like this:

[image: when looking for 'cd' in the file]

Answer (score 0):

```
:vim[grep][!] /{pattern}/[g][j] {file} ...
```

Vimgrep uses Vim's built-in regex search engine, so you can reuse the patterns from Vim's standard search command. So, I first test the search pattern the normal way using: /{pattern}/

Then enter the following:

```
:vim /CTRL+r//g %
```

where `CTRL+r/` will insert the last search pattern after the first slash. The status line will display (1 of max), where max is the maximum number of matches for the `{pattern}`. Then use the `:cnext` and `:cprev` to search for the next & previous matches and `:cfirst` and `:clast` for the first and last matches. These 4 commands can be remapped to make them faster to execute.

Answer (score 0):

A alternative is to count using the `grep` command.

Ex. If you want to search `TODO` in current file is:

```
:echo system('grep -c TODO ' . expand('%:p'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you replace your patter with the pattern itself, vim **reports the number of substitutions**.

e.g.

```
:%s/Human/Human/
```

in my documents reports `220 substitutions on 220 lines`

```
:%s/1/1/g
```

reports `294 substitutions on 252 lines` since some lines contain more than one `1`.