# Is there an easy to use software to highlight multiple keywords in a text and show count of each match?

Tags: html, search, highlight

I'm looking for an existing semi-decent software that can highlight multiple search terms simultaneously, using different colors, and show the count of each matching search term. I also need an easy way to apply the same keywords to different texts.

**EDIT**

To explain with an example, this does more or less what I need:
http://janosgyerik.github.com/highlighter/

I put this together quickly because a friend of mine needed the functionality under time pressure. I am quite tempted to build on this, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Such tool seems to be a pretty common need to me, like my friend I too often find myself wanting to do multi-keyword searches. I believe something must already exist out there I'm just unable to find it. I don't want to reinvent the wheel, if there is such existing software, I am ok with throwing away my work so far and use what exists. If there is no such software, then I'll be happy to continue hacking at this example above, I just really don't want to foolishly reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Maybe a bookmarklet starting with the js @Bill provided but with the additional features you mentioned would do the trick.

Comment: +1 for example. :-) Have you taken a look at Notepad++? It certainly can highlight different tokens in different colors (you can configure colors as you see fit), I don't know about counting. The difference might be in usage - IIRC Notepad++ hightlights on keypress / click on token - so you may need to find it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say with [Vim Multiple Search script](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip1572) this is nearly done, except for counting. But [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668623/show-count-of-matches-in-vim) tackles counting already.

If Vim is not your cup of tea, then I'd say Notepad++ (excerpt added from my comment above):

It certainly can highlight different tokens in different colors (you can configure colors as you see fit), I don't know about counting. The difference might be in usage - IIRC Notepad++ hightlights on keypress / click on token - so you may need to find it first.

Answer (score 3):

The reason that you are probably not finding mature software to do text highlighting like this is because it is only a couple of lines of code. Basically you just pass your block of text through regex and replace the matches with `<span>` tags that you can use to decorate the matches.

```
var text = $('p').text(),
    keyword = 'text',
    cls = 'hltBlue';

var pattern = '\\b' + keyword;
$('p').html(text.replace(new RegExp(pattern, 'gi'),
                    '<span class="' + cls + '">' + keyword + '</span>'));​
```

You can see an example at http://jsfiddle.net/Kmyrd/2/.

Now, if you are looking for a full featured text editor in html, there are plenty of those:

http://aloha-editor.org/
http://imperavi.com/redactor

If you want to highlight text on any website, you can usually just do `Ctrl+f`.

Comment: Then you haven't provided enough information for what you are looking for. The question 'how do I highlight multiple keywords in a body of text and show the counts' is solved with regular expressions. I've given working code to that affect.  Regular expressions are a mature technology (started in the 1950's) so dismissing that answer and claiming you want 'mature software' is like saying you refuse to use a `for` loop because you can't find somebody to sell it to you.

Comment: I guess nobody thought you were really just asking if any text editors exist (since basically ever text editor contains this functionality). When I read your question originally, it sounded is if you found that code on the internet (not written it yourself) and wanted to reuse it/figure out how it worked. Apologies for my confusion.