# Showing the number of matches during an incremental search

Tags: vim

Most IDEs’ text editors will, while you’re searching for a certain string, display information like “this is match 3 of 7”. Is there any way to get Vim to display this information when you move to a match using `n` and `N`?

Comment: I don't think "incremental search" means what you think it means.

Comment: @romainl Yeah, I guess you’re right. Although it would be nice if I could see “match 3 of 7” even as I am typing the search string.

Comment: @bdesham For the search to be both incremental (`set incsearch`) and show the count of matches it'd have to count them every time you add a character to the search. This could prove to be very resource intensive, so that's probably not a good idea. Moreover, if you use such a plugin as IndexedSearch, it can't be shown in the command line which is already occopied by the `/search`. You'd have to integrate it with your statusline or something. All in all I'd say it's easier to just go for IndexedSearch, and press `<Enter>` as you know what to search for :-)

Comment: @timss Yeah, this seems like something that would have to be baked in to Vim, both because of the UI problem and because doing such a thing in Vimscript would be either impossible or way too resource intensive.

Comment: @bdesham It seems to be possible to count the matches using `:%s/search//gn` as mentioned in [From Show Count of Matches in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668623/show-count-of-matches-in-vim) / Peter Rinker's post, but it doesn't seem to update the count every time you `n`/`N`, so it doesn't seem to be a proper solution like the ones you might be used to from full-blown IDEs. Installing said plugin is a breeze anyway using Vundle, and from what I can tell it's pretty fast at generating the match hits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[From Show Count of Matches in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668623/show-count-of-matches-in-vim):

What you want is probably the plugin [IndexedSearch](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1682).
When doing `/set` it'll display count, and the search query in the command line:

```
Match 5 of 81  /set/
```

Install it using your favorite plugin manager. I recommend [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle).

Answer (score 2):

The most common way is use the `n` flag with the substitution command.

```
:%s/set//gn
```

Or use the current pattern via `:%s//gn`. This gives you some of the feedback you asked for.

However I prefer to use `:vimgrep` and the quickfix list. Search for your pattern via:

```
:vimgrep/set/ %
```

This searches the current file, `%`, and adds the matches to the quickfix list. Then you can move through the quickfix list via `:cnext` or `:cprevious`. Upon moving through the quickfix list text will display at the bottom showing something like this `(1 of 5)`. By using the `:copen` command a window showing the quickfix results will open. Move to the pattern via pressing `<cr>` on a quickfix item.

There are some drawbacks to using `:vimgrep`.

- `:vimgrep` as of vim 7.3 does not support using the current pattern i.e. no `:vimgrep// %`. Instead one must use `<c-r>/` to pull in the search pattern register and possibly escape any `/`'s.
- The use of `%` for the current file means the file must exists, so you can not search a scratch buffer.
- `:cnext`, `:cprev`, and friends are rather verbose compared to nice and simple `n` and `N`. Adding nice mappings can overcome this. I use `[q` and `]q` from Tim Pope's excellent [unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) plugin.

For more help see:

```
:h :s_flags
:h :vimg
:h c_CTRL-R
:h quote/
:h quickfix
:h c_%
```