# Vim: show the number of instances of a name?

Tags: vim, spell-checking, vim-syntax-highlighting

How can I set up vim to show the number of times a specific spelling of a name has a occurred.

Ideally the count could be displayed by changing the color of the letters in the name. It would be fine to only know that a four letter word appeared, once, twice, thrice or more than thrice.

in the following examples bold indicates the count. The # represents separate files.

**c**at

### #

**ca**t
**ca**t

### #

**cat** 
**cat** 
**cat**

### #

**cat** 
**cat** 
**c**af
**cat** 
**cat**

Comment: Can you provide a  detailed example to make it more clear ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show Count of Matches in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668623/show-count-of-matches-in-vim)

Comment: the bold highlighting of the word cat is an example. Each time the word appears the count increases, and the count shows in the number of letters that are highlighted.

Comment: @AndyRay ZyX's answer gets at the machinery. I'm looking for that combined with highlighting so that it would show in the text itself without actively searching.

Comment: Are you looking for `hlsearch` option (`:set hlsearch`) ?

Comment: I use https://github.com/lfv89/vim-interestingwords sometimes, might be relevant to your needs

Comment: @AndyRay, in the example that I gave, the words were close together and hlsearch would kind of work (except that the cursor has to be on the word). I'm looking for an indicator that shows the occurrences of the word even when not all of the words are on the screen and without having to hover the cursor. Something that applied ZyX's solution to all the names in a document and gave the output by highlighting (or emboldening) letters in the word is what I'm looking for.